# Как отловить запрос и тело запроса при нажатии на кнопку в Selenide?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, test-automation, автоматизация, testng

При нажатии на кнопку в форме формируется определенный `POST` запрос с телом в формате `Json`.
В тесте необходимо реализовать проверку данных в этом `Json`.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно это реализовать с помощью тестов на `Selenide+Java(TestNG)`, т.е. необходимо перехватывать этот запрос.
Может кто-то встречался с подобным или есть готовое решение?

Answer (score 1):

У selenide есть [SelenideProxyServer](https://selenide.org/javadoc/4.14.1/com/codeborne/selenide/proxy/SelenideProxyServer.html).
Или так: [Selenium + BrowserMobProxy](https://habr.com/ru/post/209752/).

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: Пожалуйста, добавьте прямо в ответ, как решить поставленную задачу, используя упомянутые Вами инструменты. Спасибо.

Comment: все запросы идут через прокси, прокси пишет лог запросов сквозь себя. mobproxy делает это в формате HAR (http archive), запускается программно из теста, по истечении теста снимаете протокол с лога прокси.